# iOS: Jpeg compression increasing the Size of image (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

[image: Sample image to be compressed]

I'm trying to attach a photo(UIImage) in my iOS application from the Photos app. The original size of the image is ~10MB but when I process it with

`image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)`

the output size of the image becomes ~25MB.

Can anyone suggest as to what might be happening here?

Comment: What image format is the original image in?

Comment: @Sweeper The image was downloaded from [https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg].

The original format was ".jpg" as well.

Comment: Let's say that you save an image a quality 0.1, you'll have artefacts, pixelisaiton, if you save that one again in quality 1, you should save the "artefacts and pixelisation" as they were really parts of the image, so you'll increase your size. "It's like saving in 4K a bad image, it's still a bad image, but now it's in 4K."

Comment: I noticed that too for some images. Although not as dramatic difference as you have. Question is not though only how apple compresses, but also how do you load the original image and what you do with it. For example check that you didn't increase the size of image (e.g. if original image is 9000x16000, make are the size after re-compressing is the same or smaller), colorspace is the same as the original and so on.

Comment: I am just attaching the image from the gallery to my application, without changing any size or anything.